# I want To Display Magento PDF invoice in second page

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I am New In Magento, I want to display Some PDF Invoice Part in Second Page So Please Suggest Me. 
Please check screen shot also 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at this file :
**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php**

You have there a function called **getPdf** in which you can choose how the PDF is rendered. You also have the function **newPage** that will allow you to create a new page.

So first, extend the getPdf function and add a new page, then set your content in this new page.